# create pages automatically and dynamically in wordPress

Tags: database, wordpress, layout, plugins, automation

Is there an easy way to create pages automatically and dynamically in wordPress? Let me explain further:
I am developing a website where I have more than 20 equal pages, with the same layout, where only 3 data fields change:
Image, description, how to do it.
Is there a way, for example, to enter the data in a table and wordpress create the page automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code -

```
$check_page_exist = get_page_by_title('title_of_the_page', 'OBJECT', 'page');
// Check if the page already exists
if(empty($check_page_exist)) {
    $page_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
        'comment_status' => 'close',
        'ping_status'    => 'close',
        'post_author'    => 1,
        'post_title'     => ucwords('title_of_the_page'),
        'post_name'      => sanitize_title('title_of_the_page'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_content'   => 'Content of the page',
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'post_parent'    => 'id_of_the_parent_page_if_it_available'
        )
    );
}
```